# QGIS issue with adding OpenStreetMap basemap to my project

Tags: qgis

I've just downloaded QGIS Desktop 3.24.1 and am in the process of learning how to use/navigate my way around the software. I've come up against an issue where I've been trying to add OpenStreetMap basemap (from XYZ tiles) to my project but when I do I get the message:
OpenStreetMap: Access denied: Forbidden
When I view the error message in the Layers tab it comes up with Layer Error Access denied: Forbidden.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Its possible your organization has blocked the URL or put restrictions on the domain?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did wonder if that may have been the case so tried again on my home laptop, which worked fine. I'll follow up with out work IT team. Cheers